# Dynamic remote object url - flex mobile

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, blazeds, flex-mobile, parsley

I almost finished my project but now I want to add a dynamic server url setting in each view. Application bootstraps with config.xml and channels-config.xml (I used Parsley framework ).

**config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fx:Object xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           xmlns:services="services.*">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <services:GenBUS id="genBUS"/>
        <services:KarBUS id="karBUS"/>
        <services:UygBUS id="uygBUS"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

</fx:Object>
```

**channels-config.xml:**

```
<objects 
    xmlns="http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley 
        http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/schema/2.4/parsley-core.xsd">

    <object type="mx.messaging.ChannelSet">
        <property name="channels">
                <array>
                    <object type="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
                        <property name="uri" value="http://localhost:8080/ClinASM/messagebroker/amf"/>
                    </object>
                </array>
        </property>
    </object>

</objects>
```

The scenario is as follows: User will change url before logging into a system, and when all is done the updated endpoint url will be kept in SessionClientData.endpoint, and before the method on the server-side is called I do assign a new endpoint to Remote Object class:

```
[Inject(id="genBUS")]
public var genBUS:GenBUS;


public function login(username: String, password:String):void {

 //updating endpoint                
 genBUS.endpoint = SessionClientData.endpoint;

 //call responder is created and..              
 loginViewResponder.token = genBUS.getLoginResult(username,password);

}
```

But I'm doing something wrong - so that it's not working... Any suggestions how to make a dynamic & easy to construct channels config?

UPDATE: How to reconfigure the structure so that there'll be no "services" remote objects on clients side - I don't want to update Flex Server section each time - as in some cases there will be unreachable servers just as in my case now... Any tutorial or example configuration on this?

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting any error messages? Is the endpoint used for the calls correct? ...

Comment: I'm entering a wrong url but its working - so it uses different endpoint not the one under genBUS.endpoint

Comment: which endpoint do I need to update in order update services endpoint?!

Comment: Well, it seems `SessionClientData` isn't carrying the correct `endpoint` value then. Did you set a breakpoint there and check it?

Comment: And how can I write anything into config.xml file in Flex Mobile?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: i have to update channels-config.xml as well in order it keeps updated SessionClientData.endpoint to bootstrap or use it next time..

Comment: IS Channels-config.xml something you load at runtime?  Or is it compiled into your app?

Comment: I'm afraid its in a project structure - so its compiled into an app..